# Will melted chocolate stick to cupcake papers?

Tags: chocolate, fruit, candy, nuts, cupcakes

I plan to use mini cupcake papers in a mini cupcake pan. Then I will add fruit and/ or nuts. Then, pour melted chocolate to fill the paper. My question, once set in the fridge, will the paper stick to the chocolate or will it come off? Should I spray the paper with Pam? Please let me know, help! I don't want to make these treats to discover the paper will not come off. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience molten chocolate has never stuck to cupcake papers.

You can always make a trial with a little amount of chocolate and 1 piece of cupcake paper. It doesn't take too much effort and time.

Comment: I definitely recommend running a trial.  Empirically, I've found that the stickiness of disposable non-stick products varies by brand (i.e., the well-known brands tend to have better non-stick properties).

Comment: I wouldn’t use Pam as it will make an oily coating on the chocolate. Worse thing is you’ll have to tear off the cupcake liner. No biggie.